# How to access data from a table on the web on vba?

Tags: html, excel, vba, excel-2007

Im trying to retreive some informations from a website and for that I first had to connect.
But After, I have to retreive data from a table to put them on sheet on Excel.

HTML from the website :

```html
<table class="tab_script"></table>
<table class="tab_script">
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>N° commande SFR</td>
     <td>Nom</td>
     <td>Prenom</td>
     <td>N° Mobile</td>
     <td>N° Fixe</td>
     <td>Ville</td>
     <td>Code Postal</td>
     <td>Num. Intervention</td>
     <td>date rdv</td>
 </tr>

<tr bgcolor="#E5E5E5">
   <form method="POST"></form>
      <td></td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>telf</td>
      <td>telp</td>
      <td>PLOUGUERNEAU</td>
      <td>29880</td>
      <td>
         <a href="index.php?id=13&amp;statut=2&amp;id_inter=183530401">183530401</a></td>
      <td style="background-color:red">20/12/2018 10:00</td>
 </tr>

 <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <form method="POST"></form>
    <td></td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>numf</td>
    <td>nump</td>
    <td>PLOURIN LES MORLAIX</td>
    <td>29600</td>
    <td>
       <a href="index.php?id=13&amp;statut=2&amp;id_inter=183531538">183531538</a> 
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:#FF7F00">20/12/2018 14:30</td>
 </tr>
//.
//.
//.
```

For that, I have done my best in VBA but it doesn't work.

Code in VBA (With some tests):

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") ' Création d'objet Internet Explorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate ("https://connect-partner.sfr.fr/") ' Redirection vers cette page

' attente de fin de chargement
Do Until ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop  

'login
 Set DOCelement = ie.document.getElementsByName("login").Item
 On Error Resume Next
 DOCelement.Value = "IPCA2935" ' Affecter l'identifiant à l'élément "login"

'password
 Set DOCelement = ie.document.getElementsByName("password").Item
 DOCelement.Value = "pfTTD8IH" ' Affecter le mot de passe à l'élément "password"

'connexion
ie.document.all("connexion").Click ' Click sur le bouton Connexion
'
' Redirection vers Intervention -> Plannifiées
'
'Set maPageHtml = webBrowser1.Document
'maPageHtml.parentWindow.execScript "'disp_menu(4)'", "Javascript"

ie.document.all.Item
Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("disp_menu(4)", "JavaScript") 'DOESNT WORK
Application.Wait (2000)
'HTMLDocparentWindow.execScript "window.confirm = disp_menu(4) {return true;};"

ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(4).Click

'
'TESTS
'

'Dim td As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
'Dim tr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
'Dim a As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
'Dim trObj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
'Dim tdObj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
'Dim aObj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement

'Set tr = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
'For Each trObj In tr
'    Set td = trObj.getElementsByTagName("td")
'    For Each tdObj In td
'        ' Faire quelque chose pour chaque objet td
'        'Set ws1 = Sheets("Planifiees").Range("A1")
'        Set nom = getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText.Sheets("Planifiees").Range("A1")
'        Set adresse = tdObj.innerText.Sheets("Planifiees").Range("B1")
'        Debug.Print (nom)
'        For Each aObj In a
'            Set lien = getElementsByTagName("a").Click
'
'        Next
'    Next
'Next

'
' TESTS
'

Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim tableau As HTMLTable
Dim c As Long, r As Long
Dim tr As Object, tc As Object

Set tableau = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("tab_script")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planifiees")
    For Each tr In tableau.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        r = r + 1: c = 1
        For Each tc In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            .Cells(r, c).Value = tc.innerText
            c = c + 1
        Next
    Next
End With
```

After, I want to access to the hyperlink  but this is an other story. :)
If someone can help me, that will be great !

PS : Sorry of my english, I'm french ty

Comment: Doesn't work isn't sufficiently descriptive. What isn't working please? What is ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("disp_menu(4)", "JavaScript")  supposed to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, so I can not import the table data into my excel sheet and ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("disp_menu(4)", "JavaScript") is supposed to achieve javascript to access at my table in an other page, this action is before retrieving information from the table but it work only when the program is lunch step by step

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52528648/extract-table-from-webpage-using-vba